# Share agent work directory (C:\agent\work) across multiple containers

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-artifacts

My setup consists of a windows server on which some containers have been deployed. Every container is a build vsts agent that can perform builds and deployments. I am trying to figure if I could share the directory `C:\agent\work` across multiple containers in order to have a centralized artifacts directory.

In order to share `C:\agent:\work` I can use a specific path and create each container with volume mapping to this directory for example

```
Container1: docker run agent1 -v C:\artifacts:C:\agent\work
Container2: docker run agent2 -v C:\artifacts:C:\agent\work
```

With this solution however I tested and was able to determine that each container will keep in each own **SourceRootMapping** folder the build number and every time two containers have the same working directory this will be overridden. As I need to keep for some days artifacts I cannot continue with this solution.

Is there a way to have different vsts agents share the same `C:\agent\work` directory?

I need to share this directory so that every agent can locate files that have been created from another container for example if Agent1 creates the files under `C:\agent\work\5` I want those files to be accessible from Agent2 in order to perform the release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution which I chose for this problem was to store the artifacts on a separate directory for example `C:\artifacts` on each container. The build process will output the artifacts on a unique directory using `builID` and `$(artifactsPath) -> C:\artifacts`

Then the `C:\artifacts` directory of the containers will be shared across all containers with a mapping on the host machine:

```
docker run --name image1 -v S:\artifacts:C:\artifacts
```

**Publish artifacts:**

```
task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        ArtifactName: '$(build.BuildId)'
        publishLocation: 'FilePath'
        TargetPath: '$(artifactsPath)\$(Build.DefinitionName)\drop'
```

Comment: I am downvoting this because although it works for your specific case, it is generally not advice that others should take. The correct approach is what I said in my answer, which is to publish artifacts as part of your build with the `publish` task. Your solution will not work if you have multiple physical machines hosting your agents, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are currently taking will not work reliably, as you are seeing. You will not be able to make it work reliably.

The solution to this is simple: **Don't** try to share this folder. Let each agent in each container create its own working folders.

The way you share build outputs across jobs is to [`publish`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) them. Don't publish to a file share, publish to Azure DevOps -- file share publishing is mostly a legacy capability held over from TFS 2013 and earlier and hasn't been necessary for almost a decade.

Refer to the linked documentation for more details.

Comment: I already use `publish` artifacts, but this approach will only work for one agent with my implementation. Each agent has its own `C:\agent\work` directory and cannot locate other agents work directory

Comment: @GeralexGR Each agent **should** have its own separate working directory. That's by design. Your build process should be outputting artifacts that are consumed by other jobs, **not** reaching directly into the working folders of other agents. What you are attempting to do is a misuse of the tool and **will not work**.

Comment: Indeed I will proceed with another approach to share the artifacts in separate directories.